# Why code refactoring have such drastic effect on performance?

Tags: performance, haskell, parallel-processing

I am learning parallel programming in Haskell using Simon Marlow's book. In the chapter 4, section about shortest part in the graph there is implementation of Floyd–Warshall algorithm also included in parconc-example code samples on github. There is a notice that version with parallelism added should run slightly longer on single core machine due to monad-par overhead and way quicker when many cores available. But when I ran examples I got very surprising results. Version with parallelism added ran half the time of non-parallel one even with -N1 flag. I thought that this may be linked to many logical cores per physical one but I ran the same code on the computer with CPU without logical cores (Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU G1840 @ 2.80GHz) I got very similar results. Here is my first attempt. The code is from parconc-examples modified by me to drop old libraries dependency due to simplification.

SparseGraph.hs

```
module SparseGraph (
    Vertex, Weight,
    Graph,
    weight, insertEdge,
    randomGraph,
    mkGraph,
    toAdjMatrix,
    fromAdjMatrix,
    checksum
  ) where

import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as Map
import qualified Data.IntSet as IntSet
import Data.IntMap.Strict (IntMap)
import System.Random
import Data.Array.Unboxed

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Graph representation

-- <<Graph
type Vertex = Int
type Weight = Int

type Graph = IntMap (IntMap Weight)

weight :: Graph -> Vertex -> Vertex -> Maybe Weight
weight g i j = do
  jmap <- Map.lookup i g
  Map.lookup j jmap
-- >>

insertEdge :: Vertex -> Vertex -> Weight -> Graph -> Graph
insertEdge i j w m = Map.insertWith Map.union i (Map.singleton j w) m

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Testing

randomGraph :: StdGen -> Int -> Int -> Int -> (Graph, [Vertex])
randomGraph g max_vertex max_weight edges = (mat, vs)
  where
      (g1,g2) = split g
      (g3,g4) = split g2
      is = take edges $ randomRs (0,max_vertex) g1
      js = take edges $ randomRs (0,max_vertex) g3
      ws = take edges $ randomRs (1,max_weight) g4

      mat = foldr ins Map.empty (zip3 is js ws)
        where ins (i,j,w) = insertEdge i j w

      vs = IntSet.elems (IntSet.fromList (is ++ js))

mkGraph :: [[Int]] -> Graph
mkGraph xss = Map.fromList (zipWith row [0..] xss)
  where
   row i xs = (i, Map.fromList [ (j, w) | (j,w) <- zip [0..] xs, w /= 100 ])

type AdjMatrix = UArray (Int,Int) Weight

toAdjMatrix :: Int -> Graph -> AdjMatrix
toAdjMatrix k m = accumArray (\_ e -> e) 999 ((0,0),(k,k))
      [ ((i,j),w) | (i,jmap) <- Map.toList m, (j,w) <- Map.toList jmap ]

fromAdjMatrix :: AdjMatrix -> [[Int]]
fromAdjMatrix m = chunk (k+1) (elems m)
  where
   (_, (k,_)) = bounds m

chunk :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunk _ [] = []
chunk n xs = as : chunk n bs
  where (as,bs) = splitAt n xs

checksum :: Graph -> Int
checksum m = sum (concat (map Map.elems (Map.elems m)))
```

FwPar.hs

```
module FwPar ( perform ) where

import Control.Monad.Par.Scheds.Trace
  -- gives slightly better results than Control.Monad.Par with monad-par-0.3.4
import System.Environment
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as Map
import Data.IntMap.Strict (IntMap)
import System.Random
import Data.List

import SparseGraph

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- shortestPaths

shortestPaths :: [Vertex] -> Graph -> Graph
shortestPaths vs g = foldl' update g vs
 where
-- <<update
  update g k = runPar $ do
    m <- Map.traverseWithKey (\i jmap -> spawn (return (shortmap i jmap))) g
    traverse get m
-- >>
   where
    shortmap :: Vertex -> IntMap Weight -> IntMap Weight
    shortmap i jmap = foldr shortest Map.empty vs
        where shortest j m =
                case (old,new) of
                   (Nothing, Nothing) -> m
                   (Nothing, Just w ) -> Map.insert j w m
                   (Just w,  Nothing) -> Map.insert j w m
                   (Just w1, Just w2) -> Map.insert j (min w1 w2) m
                where
                  old = Map.lookup j jmap
                  new = do w1 <- weight g i k
                           w2 <- weight g k j
                           return (w1+w2)

perform :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
perform h n = do
  let g = mkStdGen 9999
  let (mat,vs) = randomGraph g h 100 n
  print (checksum (shortestPaths vs mat))
```

FwSingle.hs

```
module FwSingle ( perform ) where

import System.Environment
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as Map
import Data.IntMap.Strict (IntMap)
import System.Random
import Data.List
import SparseGraph

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- shortestPaths

-- <<shortestPaths
shortestPaths :: [Vertex] -> Graph -> Graph
shortestPaths vs g = foldl' update g vs            -- <1>
 where
  update g k = Map.mapWithKey shortmap g           -- <2>
   where
     shortmap :: Vertex -> IntMap Weight -> IntMap Weight
     shortmap i jmap = foldr shortest Map.empty vs -- <3>
        where shortest j m =
                case (old,new) of                  -- <6>
                   (Nothing, Nothing) -> m
                   (Nothing, Just w ) -> Map.insert j w m
                   (Just w,  Nothing) -> Map.insert j w m
                   (Just w1, Just w2) -> Map.insert j (min w1 w2) m
                where
                  old = Map.lookup j jmap          -- <4>
                  new = do w1 <- weight g i k      -- <5>
                           w2 <- weight g k j
                           return (w1+w2)

perform :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
perform h n = do
  let g = mkStdGen 9999
  let (mat,vs) = randomGraph g h 100 n
  print (checksum (shortestPaths vs mat))
```

Main.hs

```
module Main where

import qualified FwPar as P
import qualified FwSingle as S
import System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = do
    [m, h, n] <- (fmap . fmap) read getArgs
    case m of
        0 -> S.perform h n
        1 -> P.perform h n
```

Here are the results on two core machine without logical cores.

cabal exec fwsparse -- 0 1000 800 +RTS -s // non-parallel version

```
466229
   5,802,636,672 bytes allocated in the heap
     182,812,432 bytes copied during GC
         487,440 bytes maximum residency (95 sample(s))
          34,400 bytes maximum slop
               7 MiB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      1289 colls,     0 par    0.312s   0.314s     0.0002s    0.0114s
  Gen  1        95 colls,     0 par    0.053s   0.053s     0.0006s    0.0113s

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time   19.155s  ( 19.107s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.364s  (  0.366s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.003s  (  0.006s elapsed)
  Total   time   19.522s  ( 19.480s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    302,938,380 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  98.1% of total user, 98.1% of total elapsed
```

cabal exec fwsparse -- 1 1000 800 +RTS -s // parallel version on single core

```
466229
     779,668,784 bytes allocated in the heap
      38,225,280 bytes copied during GC
         299,016 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          30,136 bytes maximum slop
               7 MiB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       181 colls,     0 par    0.062s   0.063s     0.0003s    0.0007s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.001s   0.001s     0.0003s    0.0005s

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    7.849s  (  7.855s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.063s  (  0.063s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.004s  (  0.011s elapsed)
  Total   time    7.916s  (  7.930s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    99,336,996 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  99.1% of total user, 99.1% of total elapsed
```

cabal exec fwsparse -- 1 1000 800 +RTS -s -N2 // parallel version on multiple cores

```
466229
     810,641,208 bytes allocated in the heap
      28,512,928 bytes copied during GC
         244,152 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          37,288 bytes maximum slop
              12 MiB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       130 colls,   130 par    0.059s   0.053s     0.0004s    0.0013s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     1 par    0.001s   0.000s     0.0002s    0.0003s

  Parallel GC work balance: 16.11% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 6 (1 bound, 5 peak workers (5 total), using -N2)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    8.924s  (  4.638s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.060s  (  0.053s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.007s  (  0.008s elapsed)
  Total   time    8.991s  (  4.700s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    90,838,887 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  99.3% of total user, 98.7% of total elapsed
```

Later I decided to simplify code further since FwPar and FwSingle differs only one line. Here SparseGraph.hs stays the same and everything else is put into Main.hs.

```
module Main where

import System.Environment ( getArgs )
import SparseGraph
    ( checksum, randomGraph, weight, Graph, Vertex, Weight )
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as Map
import Data.IntMap.Strict (IntMap)
import Control.Monad.Par.Scheds.Trace ( spawn, get, runPar )
import Data.List ( foldl' )
import System.Random ( mkStdGen )

main :: IO ()
main = do
    [m, h, n] <- (fmap . fmap) read getArgs
    perform m h n

shortestPaths :: Int -> [Vertex] -> Graph -> Graph
shortestPaths mode vs g = foldl' update g vs
 where
  update g k = if mode == 0
    then Map.mapWithKey shortmap g
    else
    runPar $ do
        m <- Map.traverseWithKey (\i jmap -> spawn (return (shortmap i jmap))) g
        traverse get m
   where
    shortmap :: Vertex -> IntMap Weight -> IntMap Weight
    shortmap i jmap = foldr shortest Map.empty vs
        where shortest j m =
                case (old,new) of
                   (Nothing, Nothing) -> m
                   (Nothing, Just w ) -> Map.insert j w m
                   (Just w,  Nothing) -> Map.insert j w m
                   (Just w1, Just w2) -> Map.insert j (min w1 w2) m
                where
                  old = Map.lookup j jmap
                  new = do w1 <- weight g i k
                           w2 <- weight g k j
                           return (w1+w2)

perform :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
perform m h n = do
  let g = mkStdGen 9999
  let (mat,vs) = randomGraph g h 100 n
  print (checksum (shortestPaths m vs mat))
```

When I ran commands mentioned above I got results exactly as predicted in the book. Here are examples run on 6 cores and 12 logical machine (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz)

cabal exec fwsparse 0 1000 800 -- +RTS -s

```
466229
   5,802,734,976 bytes allocated in the heap
     182,812,448 bytes copied during GC
         487,440 bytes maximum residency (95 sample(s))
          30,248 bytes maximum slop
               7 MiB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      1289 colls,     0 par    0.146s   0.147s     0.0001s    0.0004s
  Gen  1        95 colls,     0 par    0.024s   0.024s     0.0002s    0.0004s

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time   12.030s  ( 12.019s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.169s  (  0.171s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.010s elapsed)
  Total   time   12.201s  ( 12.200s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    482,345,993 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  98.6% of total user, 98.5% of total elapsed
```

cabal exec fwsparse 1 1000 800 -- +RTS -s

```
466229
   6,396,792,224 bytes allocated in the heap
     333,942,784 bytes copied during GC
         529,296 bytes maximum residency (171 sample(s))
          32,400 bytes maximum slop
               7 MiB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      1351 colls,     0 par    0.272s   0.273s     0.0002s    0.0006s
  Gen  1       171 colls,     0 par    0.059s   0.060s     0.0003s    0.0007s

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time   13.523s  ( 13.625s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.331s  (  0.333s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  Total   time   13.855s  ( 13.961s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    473,013,596 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  97.6% of total user, 97.6% of total elapsed
```

cabal exec fwsparse 1 1000 800 -- +RTS -s -N6

```
466229
   6,579,039,008 bytes allocated in the heap
      75,768,608 bytes copied during GC
         348,424 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          66,912 bytes maximum slop
              30 MiB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       322 colls,   322 par    0.213s   0.133s     0.0004s    0.0010s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     1 par    0.001s   0.001s     0.0005s    0.0009s

  Parallel GC work balance: 6.18% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 14 (1 bound, 13 peak workers (13 total), using -N6)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.004s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  MUT     time   16.853s  (  3.224s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.214s  (  0.134s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.002s  (  0.010s elapsed)
  Total   time   17.073s  (  3.370s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    390,385,082 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  98.7% of total user, 95.7% of total elapsed
```

I have no idea why only reducing this to one file caused such change. I even put these two files (FwPar.hs and FwSingle.hs) into text comparator and found nothing unusual.

Comment: I'd try replacing `update g k = if mode == 0 then ... else ...` with `update = if mode == 0 then \g k -> ... else \g k -> ...` so that `mode==0` is evaluated only once. You probbaly need more refactoring to make that work since you use `g` in the nested `where`s (maybe you can use a `let` instead?).

Comment: @chi Replaced it. It ran much quicker but with the same order. Parallel version on single core were the slowest (3.3 seconds),, parallel version on multiple cores were the quickest (1.7 second). Non parallel version achieved 2.6 seconds.

Comment: @chi Sorry, I did something wrong. I didn't see that this modification changed the result. Here is code if someone has idea why. update = if mode == 0 then \g k -> let shortmap' = shortmap k
                                      in Map.mapWithKey shortmap' g
                        else \g k -> let shortmap' = shortmap k
                                      in runPar $ do
                                          m <- Map.traverseWithKey (\i jmap -> spawn (return (shortmap' i jmap))) g
                                          traverse get m

Comment: Subtle changes in Haskell can make _enormous_ differences to performance.